# Reverse an object with array_reverse PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, foreach, rss

I am trying to process an RSS feed however want to do it in reverse so latest item is imported last to keep the order correct.

```
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$rss = array_reverse($rss);
foreach($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
  echo $entry->title;
}
```

However above just throws `array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array` & `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error. How can i reverse the array so the for each works backwards?

Comment: You're reversing `$x`, what does that have to do with the XML?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry poor copy and pasting. See above.

Comment: `$rss` is an object, not an array.

Comment: Yeah i get thats my issue i want to reverse an object then?

Comment: You don't want to reverse the whole object, you just want to reverse `$rss->channel->item`.

Comment: So i tried: $rss = array_reverse($rss->channel->item); but same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169472/discussion-between-harri-and-barmar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$rss->channel->item` is a `SimpleXMLElement` object, not an array. You can iterate with `foreach`, but other array operations will not work.

If you want to iterate in reverse, get the count and then access each element by its index, counting the index down.

```
$items = $rss->channel->item;
$count = count($items);
for ($i = $count-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $items[$i]->title;
}
```

Comment: Epic i didnt need the children bit i think that was pulling the child nodes from item but without children it seems to be working a treat

Comment: Yeah that's what worked for me. Thanks so much your a legend!

Comment: Perfect Solution. Thankyou So Much.